# Blog pagination WITHOUT using max_num_pages

Tags: pagination, loop, blog

WP 3.2.1

I'm in a bit of a bind.  I have to create some pagination for the blog, but I believe I'm running into the bug described [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/archives-not-showing-nextprev-windows-only-crazy?replies=5), and I don't have authorization to fiddle with the server's `php.ini` file.

So, I need to find a way to create pagination for the blog without having max_num_pages.  Is that possible?  I don't want to re-engineer the blog loop if I don't have to.

EDIT: max_num_pages isn't even in the list of query_vars when I print them with `print_r($wp_query->query_vars);`

EDIT 2: Similarly, found_posts isn't in $wp_query, either.  If it helps, I'm using a modified version of Avia as the theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
ini_set( 'mysql.trace_mode', 0 );
```

… in your `functions.php`.

Maybe an .htaccess entry …

```
php_value mysql.trace_mode 0
```

… works too. I haven’t tested it.

Comment: ini_set doesn't work.  print_r($wp_query->max_num_pages) still prints 0.  I don't have access to the .htaccess

Comment: `.htaccess` should be right in the root folder of your WP installation. You don't have access to that?